# Storing html element structure inside Python data structures

Tags: python

I need an advice on how to structure html elements inside some data structure in python, that would be passed around various functions.I understand that could be easily done with xpath, but right now I'm looking for a different solution.So, all I want is to express this kind of structure:

```
<div class="someclass">
   <div class="class">
      <a href="#">sometext</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

,in XPath I would write something like this '/div/div/a'.Right now I'm experimenting with mixing dicts and lists, but can't figure out the right structure.

Comment: Like XML, HTML is a **tree**.

Comment: divmod's nevow has "stan"